# Fire-fox add-on. Confusion about publishing / updating process

Tags: firefox-addon

I have created a Firefox add-in via the SDK.

A user should be able to install this directly from my webpage. I am following these directions https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Installing_Extensions_and_Themes_From_Web_Pages

It has not been reviewed/approved.

However, I am confused about:

1) Must the add-on undergo the review process even if it is NOT made available in the Mozilla gallery?

I'm getting an error ("..does not match the add-on Firefox expected.") when trying to install it and don't know if this is because of its non-reviewed status.

2) It looks like updates also have to undergo the review process. For approved updates to take affect, do people need to have installed the add-on via the gallery? Or can they have added it via my website? Is there any way to auto-update non-reviewed/approved add-ons.

3) How long is the approval process? Can it really take several weeks to publish an add-on? What's 'normal'?

How about for updates? If I discover a bug in my code, or need to make an improvement, can it really take up to 10 days(!) for the fix to be applied across all users!?

3b) My add-on only works if the user is logged into my service/website. It collects data from the website and needs to know what account to send it to. If you're not logged in, you get a message to please log in. Can such an add-on be approved? It's more cumbersome to test.

4) When I wrote the add-on I had assumed that this would be similar to creating a Chrome extension, which was essentially instant. **It seems that this is, instead, a cumbersome process with big risks; especially the slow update process is risk factor. Or, have I completely misunderstood something?**

Comment: I'm pretty sure yes you have to get it reviewed. So what you do is just upload to AMO (gallery) get it reviewed and then upload the xpi to your website as well, it will now work, but it has to work on AMO in order to work on your site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) Must the add-on undergo the review process even if it is NOT made available in the Mozilla gallery?

At the time of writing: Yes, you can self-host/self-publish your add-ons.

We do this for nightly builds of some of our add-ons, e.g. https://github.com/scriptish/scriptish-nightlies/releases and https://code.downthemall.net/nightly/

> I'm getting an error ("..does not match the add-on Firefox expected.") when trying to install it and don't know if this is because of its non-reviewed status.

This is the error you get when the supplied hash does not match the XPI you serve (or maybe fail to provide a hash at all via when using the install trigger).

> 2) It looks like updates also have to undergo the review process. For approved updates to take affect, do people need to have installed the add-on via the gallery? Or can they have added it via my website? Is there any way to auto-update non-reviewed/approved add-ons.

For AMO (addons.mozilla.org) hosted add-ons: Yes, updates will have to undergo the review process.

But it is possible to have a custom `updateURL`. See [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Extension_Versioning,_Update_and_Compatibility#Formatting_in_Firefox_4_and_later), which admittedly wasn't updated in a while but generally should still apply.

The most important bits:

- Have an `update.rdf` and have your `updateURL` in your `install.rdf` point to it (i.e. plan ahead).
- The `update.rdf` must be correctly formatted and should contain a hash (preferably sha-256 at the moment IIRC)
- The `update.rdf` must be either served over https *or* signed by McCoy (PITA) or some other compatible tool such as [spock](https://github.com/bard/spock) (also PITA).

E.g. this is the (auto-generated) update.rdf we're using for the DownThemAll! nightly:
http://code.downthemall.net/nightly/update-trunk.rdf

And this is the very quick and very dirty python script that generates it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
import sys
from zipfile import ZipFile
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString
from hashlib import sha256

TMPL = """<?xml version="1.0"?>
<RDF xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:em="http://www.mozilla.org/2004/em-rdf#"><Description about="urn:mozilla:extension:dta@downthemall.net"><em:updates><Seq><li><Description>
<em:version/>
</Description></li></Seq></em:updates></Description></RDF>
"""

_,xpi,out,url = sys.argv
with open(xpi, "rb") as ip:
  xh = sha256(ip.read()).hexdigest()
rdf = parseString(TMPL)
xpi = ZipFile(xpi)
inrdf = parseString(xpi.read("install.rdf"))
ver = inrdf.getElementsByTagName("em:version")[0]

el = rdf.getElementsByTagName("em:version")[0]
el.appendChild(rdf.createTextNode(ver.firstChild.nodeValue))
el = el.parentNode

for ta in inrdf.getElementsByTagName("em:targetApplication"):
  d = ta.getElementsByTagName("Description")[0]
  ul = rdf.createElement("em:updateLink")
  ul.appendChild(rdf.createTextNode(url))
  d.appendChild(ul)
  uh = rdf.createElement("em:updateHash")
  uh.appendChild(rdf.createTextNode("sha256:{0}".format(xh)))
  d.appendChild(uh)
  el.appendChild(ta)

with open(out, "wb") as op:
  op.write(rdf.toxml())
```

> 3) How long is the approval process? Can it really take several weeks to publish an add-on? What's 'normal'?

This varies per add-on and overall workload, but can take some time. See the [Add-ons blog](http://blog.mozilla.com/addons/) for updates.

> How about for updates? If I discover a bug in my code, or need to make an improvement, can it really take up to 10 days(!) for the fix to be applied across all users!?

In general yes, but for grave bugs, in particular security issues or "everything broke" issues, you can ping the amo-editors for an expedited review which can bring down the review time significantly.

> 3b) My add-on only works if the user is logged into my service/website. It collects data from the website and needs to know what account to send it to. If you're not logged in, you get a message to please log in. Can such an add-on be approved? It's more cumbersome to test.

Yes, such add-ons are regularly approved. For full reviews you'll usually need to provide a test account, though.

> 4) When I wrote the add-on I had assumed that this would be similar to creating a Chrome extension, which was essentially instant. It seems that this is, instead, a cumbersome process with big risks; especially the slow update process is risk factor. Or, have I completely misunderstood something?

Quite frankly, Chrome's review process pretty much prefers developers over users while with mozilla it is the other way round: the user comes first.
So yes, it is a bit more cumbersome in particular to get Fully Reviewed status. And it takes a quite a bit longer.

You might consider this a risk when it comes to AMO. On the other hand you can still self-publish.

You might also consider this free consulting: AMO editors will regularly point out security issues, code defects incl. performance problems, functional defects, etc. So you get another layer of code review and QA testing for free.

(Chrome seems to claim that their permission system and sandboxing thwarts most threats, so there is no need for an actual review, but this is pretty much a false assumption as demonstrate by Chrome extension malware time and time again; You can still steal cookies, have XSS on steroids and do a lot of other harm).

Comment: Thanks for providing such a thorough answer! For the self-hosting with automatic updates, will be user need to restart Firefox? For both the initial install and updates?

Comment: Restarts depend on whether the add-on is restartless (`bootstrapped` or SDK add-on) or not. This has nothing to do with where the add-on is hosted.